# Django model (inheritence, one-to-many, many-to-many)

Tags: django, inheritance, model

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class Book(models.Model):

    class TYPE_OF_BOOK(models.TextChoices):
        COMPUTER = 'COM', _('Computer')
        NATURAL_SCIENCE = 'NAT', _('Natual_Science')
        ECONOMY = 'ECO', _('ECONOMY')
        HISTORY = 'HIS', _('History')

    type_of_book = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=TYPE_OF_BOOK.choices,
        default=True,
   )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    published_date = models.DateField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Review(models.Model):
   book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reviews')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField()
    grade = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

At this moment, each book can have reviews.

How to approach book by average of grade in reviews which the book has.

--extra explain--

1. I tried one-to-many and can access book.reviews. But I can't approach book by grade
2. I tried many-to-many and can't access book.reviews

Answer (score 0):

You can [**`.annotate(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the books with:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

Book.objects.annotate(
    rating=Avg('reviews__grade')
)
```

The `Book` objects that arise from *this* `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.rating` that is the average of the `grade`s of the *related* `Review` objects. If there are no related reviews, the field will have `None` as value (not to be confused with zero `0`).